# Avoid using db.UserProperty() when storing user objects

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**Edit 08/01/2014**

As of this edit time I realised that the subject property `db.UserProperty()` is removed from the ndb datastore at least. Good!

---

So... There is the db.UserProperty() model class that stores the Email address
in Unicode order. Why and how does it differ from a unicode string that just stores the

```
users.get_current_user().email()
```

in a db.StringProperty() lets say?

Is it safe to use it like:

```
class LocalUser(db.Model):

    user_account = db.UserProperty()

my_local_user = LocalUser.all().filter("user_account=", users.get_current_user().get())
```

**EDIT**

The reason that I asked this question is because many examples and some books for Google App Engine use db.UserProperty() for Models in order to save the user instance and later on when the user comes back they can get the db.Model instance for that specific user.

In my opinion this opens vulnerabilities in your application's users validation.

The answer from @RocketDonkey explains the roots of my query and gives a good explanation on why not store db.UserProperty() User object instances for storing user authentication.

The correct way is to store the **user_id()** property of the User instance because it is unique and fixed for every user.

P.S. Sorry for my english. If someone can edit, it will be appreciated.

Comment: "In my opinion this opens vulnerabilities in your application's users validation." - what vulnerabilities?

Comment: @NickJohnson you register to my app with your openid having as email eg. nick@tiki.com . After 1 year you delete your email, for various reasons. After some time another person registers that email address. 
He uses my app. What happens ? He gets identified as nick!!! And what if he was a privileged user?

Comment: In the case of OpenID, you're identified by your OpenID URL, not your email address. In the case of Google Accounts, you're identified by your User ID, not your email address. In either case, it should be unique, indefinitely.

Comment: @NickJohnson yes but what does the userproperty store? Your email. So if you are storing this and making your validation upon this property then it's a problem.

Comment: As well I can store the email if I needed to, in many other property types.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that ndb.UserProperty has been removed? It is still in google.appengine.ext.model on GAE 1.9.13, isn't it?

Comment: @Marc i think its no longer in the docs

Comment: It's still here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types

Comment: @Marc Indeed. Strange I thought it was removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**  As indicated by the [documentation on User objects](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects):

> Both the db and NDB libraries have UserProperty property types so that
>   applications can store user values. However, since these values become
>   invalid when users change email address, most applications have no
>   good use for this feature.

`User` instances are always unique and can be compared, but since they are represented in the datastore as the unique `user_id` (which will always be unique) and the user's email address, a user changing their email address will render the comparison useless (this is also indicated in the docs as another reason not to store it). Getting back to your original question (uses of `db.UserProperty`), this seems to indicate that for most situations, there is not a valid reason to store User instances in the datastore (I'll update this if I do come across a reason).

Comment: So it's the User object instance is unique? 
I mean you store the user object at A.user_account and then the user changes his email address. Will that return the same user in my db? Currently I am saving the User.user_id , that is a perm id and unique. I can understand the usage of the User class but saving an instance that will not validate back upon email change I don't get the reason...

Comment: @JimmyKane Actually I did a bit more reading (I admittedly had done things in the way you mention above anytime I needed that functionality) and I came across https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects. At the end, in regards to actually storing the data (as opposed to using `User` objects outside of the datastore), it says `However, since these values become invalid when users change email address, most applications have no good use for this feature.` I'll amend my answer to reflect this (and apologies for not researching more before posting :) ).

Comment: These where the things that I had read. I did my homework good before I posted the question. So another reason that I posted the question was because 2/3 books and good books about app engine save the User instance and use it for validation. Also many examples not related to the User object in the google app engine official documentation use the User object as well. This becomes a serious security flaw if I create an adress with you ex address and so on.

Comment: @JimmyKane Yeah, I definitely agree with your perspective - as the user ID is unique and can be compared, storing that in the datastore and doing lookups against it would seemingly provide a much more reliable way to query since despite the underlying email address changing, the `user_id` would remain constant. If you want, I'm happy to delete this answer as it seems we both arrived at the same conclusion, and since there may be others who have come across situations in which storing a `UserProperty` does in fact make sense.

Comment: Updated the question and the title. If you like make any edit if it's needed to make it clear for future users that read this. Thanks a lot for you time.

Comment: Also I think that this should be a promoted question, I dont care that I made the query but because other people should know about this.

Comment: @JimmyKane No problem at all - we both learned something :) Good luck with everything going forward.

Comment: Seems that the property is gone from the ndb

Comment: So, one should use `user.user_id` if one is concerned about users changing their email address?