# Is Google Account user_id() unique for all time? (i.e. never re-used)

Tags: google-app-engine, email, google-account

Is `user_id()` unique for all time?

That is, even if a `Google Account` is deleted, the `user_id()` of that 
deleted account will never appear again in any other `user_id`, right?

We are clarifying our understanding of this statement from 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_user_id

> user_id()
>
> If the email address is associated with a `Google account`, `user_id` 
>   returns the unique permanent ID of the user, a string. This ID is
>   always  the same for the user regardless of whether the user changes
>   her `email`  address.

Comment: Is there even a way to change your username? I thought you can just create a new one but the old one stays there.

Comment: The word "permanent" seems to imply that yes, this is for all time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is.  It is a String of digits that is immutable to your email changes etc. Other properties such as email, nickname and other properties are mutable.

**EDIT**

It is unique!

From https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects

> The User object for a valid user can provide a **unique ID** value for the
>   user that stays the same even if the user changes her email address.
>   The user_id() method returns this ID, a str value.
>
> The User object has the same form no matter which method of
>   authentication your app uses. If you switch authentication options
>   from Google Accounts to OpenID, existing User objects in the datastore
>   are still valid.

Also take care beacuse the UserProperty is mutable as well  as [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999106/avoid-using-db-userproperty-when-storing-user-objects).

Comment: the part that I'm trying to clarify is whether the immutable user id could ever be assigned to a future user after the existing user deletes his Google Account. The ID is unique and permanent for a User, but is it forever unique even after a user deletes their account.

Comment: @CarterMaslan
See updated answer, and discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999106/avoid-using-db-userproperty-when-storing-user-objects

Comment: @CarterMaslan I think it stated clearly: The User object for a valid user can provide a unique ID value for the user that stays the same even if the user changes her email address.