# Differentiating logged-in users as admin and normal user in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an app in GAE. Application provides different view depending upon whether logged-in user is admin or normal user. I want to use 'Google Apps domain' as Authentication Type. So that all user of my domain can login into the application and use it.

Here, application can't differentiate a logged-in as admin or normal user. Somehow I should make an user as admin and as soon as that user logs in, application should use admin view for that user. Is there any way to tell application that a particular user is admin?

If we have our own USER table, we can mark any user as admin. Whenever a user logs into the app, app can consult USER table to check if user is admin or not? But in my scenario, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is what you describe not possible? The object representing the logged-in user is an instance of `google.appengine.api.users.User`. That object has a user_id property. You can use that ID as a field in your own user model, to which you can add a field determining whether or not they are an admin.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it possible to know user_id of particular user by using their email id?

Comment: No, but you could store that in your user model too.

Comment: I think this is the way I should implement. Create User model and store 'user_id'(of User that I want to make him as admin) in it, as soon as user with that user_id logs in, Application should consider him as a admin. Is my understanding correct? But the problem is I don't know 'user_id' of the user whom I want to make as admin to store in my User model.
I don't want to use email address because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999106/avoid-using-db-userproperty-when-storing-user-objects

Comment: To store user_id in user model, I should know 'user_id' of the user. Which is not possible until user logs in.

Comment: Well, exactly. Your proposed implementation sounds backwards. When a user logs in for the first time, you create an entity in your user model with their user_id and email. Then, you do whatever you need to do to ascertain whether or not they should be an admin, and update the record accordingly.

Comment: @rajpy The first time when you are creating the user you could also use the [users.is_current_user_admin()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions#is_current_user_admin) function to determine if that user is an admin of the app so you will always have a system with the default administrators.

Comment: Ok thanks. Many user can login into the application. To ascertain a user as admin, I should know in-advance which user can be admin. So, I will store that user's mail id(which I know) in user model and compare logged-in user's email id with store 'email id' in user model, if it matches, application marks him as admin.

Comment: @Lipis: Thanks, I din't know that function, will look into it.

Comment: @Lipis: According to the link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers "An administrator is a user who can access the Administration Console for the application". What if I want to change administrator to different user?

Sorry, I am asking too many questions. I just started learning App Engine.

Comment: @rajpy You can have many administrators.. it was just an idea on when you are creating a new user in your own model.. you could set the admin value for them if that particular user is an admin of the Application or not from the beginning. If that confuses you.. you can stick to the initial plan and do that a bit later.

Comment: @Lipis: Thanks. I will see how it goes..:)